# Exposing different object in 2 different BP connection, use same 8181 port?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, blueprism

If I have created two connections in Blue Prism and I expose objects in both of them, would they use the same default port of 8181? Would there be some conflict and what to do for such scenarios?

Comment: Ports are set when you setup a connection so your question is a bit miss leading/confusing. Also, if there is a conflict.. change one of the ports. I suspect I haven't understood your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in two different database connections, if you expose objects, they would use port 8181 but show up with different names if the objects names are different. For interacting with objects from third party applications you would have to provide HTTP authentication and give username/password of the database connection you have to use.